# Module not found: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'

Tags: reactjs, pagination

**I'm trying to use react-pagination and it's working very good but without bootstrap. when I tried to use it and import bootstrap, that error above appeared. Can anyone please help me with this error**

```
require("bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less");

      <ReactPaginate
              previousLabel={'Previous'}
              nextLabel={'Next'}
              breakLabel={'...'}
              breakClassName={'break-me'}
              pageCount={(products.length / productsPerPage)}
              marginPagesDisplayed={2}
              pageRangeDisplayed={5}
              onPageChange={ (e)=> {console.log(1);
                setFromProduct(e.selected*productsPerPage)}}
              containerClassName={'pagination'}
              subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
              activeClassName={'active'}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't use LESS but it does use Scss.

Comment: So, hur can I add bootstrap this my pagination, it's working very good but without bootstrap?

Comment: Are you using webpack or maybe Create-React-App?

If you're using webpack, you'd need to configure loaders for scss. 

If you're using CRA, you might have to `eject`